¿Como hacer que un JSON se visualice en un archivo .txt y no en el navegador?
Buenas noches con todos .
Como puedo hacer para que un JSON se visualice en un documento .txt en vez de un navegador?
Este es un ejemplo echo en PHP.
$RegistroArray = [ 
        "results" => [
              "nombre" => $Nombre, 
              "apellido" => $Apellido, 
              "pais" => $Pais 
              
           ] 
     ]; 

Mi salida sería :
{
   "results":{
      "nombre":"Juan",
      "Apellido":"Flores",
      "Pais":"Mexico"
   }
}

Y pues esto me visualiza en un navegador , pero yo quiero que no se asi , sino apenas entre a el link JSON pues me habrá un cuadro de descarga, para ponerle un nombre a mí archivo.txt y al final descarge y se visualice dentro de mi archivo .txt  . Como lograr esto en  PHP .

¿Cómo lanzas la descarga? ¿es un link con una etiqueta <a> a un PHP que produce únicamente el JSON?

@jachguate no , sino me refiero a que hay JSON que cuando lo escribes por la URL automáticamente te habre una ventana para que lo descargues , como fichero .txt .. Osea no te muestra el JSON en el mismo navegador , sino por un fichero . Por eso decía . No eh encontrado información de esto

Necesitas crear y descargar tu archivo .txt con el contenido del Json deseado.
Prueba con
$nombre = 'Juan';
$apellido = 'Flores';
$pais = 'Mexico';

$registroArray = [
    "results" => [
          "nombre" => $nombre,
          "apellido" => $apellido,
          "pais" => $pais
       ]
 ];

$json = json_encode($registroArray);
// Para ver el resultado
// echo '<pre>';
//  var_dump($json);
// echo '</pre>';

$file = "OCHOAjson.txt";
$txt = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($txt, $json);
fclose($txt);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
readfile($file);

El resultado es un archivo .txt con el siguiente contenido

{"results":{"nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Flores","pais":"Mexico"}}

Como consejo te recomiendo nombrar las variables en inicial minúscula.

Si te está mostrando los datos dentro del navegador, es porque tu servidor está indicando que el contenido es adecuado para ser presentado allí.
Para evitarlo, tienes que enviar las cabeceras adecuadas, lo que, desde PHP implica usar la función header() antes de producir cualquier salida del script.
La cabecera relevante, en este caso, es Content-Disposition, pues esta indica si el contenido se debe mostrar dentro del navegador o tratarse como una descarga, de la documentación:

In a regular HTTP response, the Content-Disposition response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.

(El resaltado es mío).
En esta misma cabecera indicamos el nombre del archivo, por ejemplo:
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"

Además, son deseables:

Content-Type. En el ejemplo de abajo, en lugar de txt, que es lo que pides en la pregunta, estoy indicando el MIME type de JSON, pues considero que es más apropiado, pero si realmente quieres que el usuario quede con un archivo TXT y al hacer doble clic lo abra con su aplicación de textos por defecto, como el bloc de notas en windows, entonces cambia el MIME type por text/plain y el nombre de archivo a la extensión .txt.
Cache-Control suponiendo que el contenido varía con cada llamada, te aseguras que el servidor sea quien siempre responde.
Content-Length para que el navegador pueda mostrar el progreso de la descarga si el resultado es grande.

Ejemplo:
<?php
$registroArray = [
    "results" => [
          "nombre" => "Juan",
          "apellido" => "Pérez",
          "pais" => "México"
       ]
 ];
$json = json_encode($registroArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="datos.json"');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($json));
echo($json);
?>?>

Sugiero ser cuidadoso en indicar la codificación que produce tu script. En este caso, mi script está guardado con codificación UTF-8, y todos los datos vienen de él, por lo que indico esa codificación en el header Content-Type y me aseguro que se produzca una salida sin aplicar secuencias de escape pasando el parámetro JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE a json_encode(). Puede que esto no aplique a tu caso y debas ajustar ambos parámetros para que tu salida sea consistente.
